# can you show me how to position bottons with boostrap?

Tags: css

I am triying to position bottons  like in this images shown in the picture for my website, can you please show to do it in boostrap , because I have tried to do it with

align="center"

it didn't work

[image]

Comment: Have you read the bootstrap docs? Done any research on your own? Because align is neither a CSS attribute nor a Bootstrap CSS class, which makes me think you are just trying stuff at random rather than reading the documentation.

Comment: Also, please proofread your posts. Boostrap is some sort of restraint for ghosts. Bootstrap is a popular CSS framework.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap provides a number of CSS classes that can be used to position elements on a page. The `.btn` class can be used to style buttons, `.btn-group` can be used to group buttons together.

To center a button, you can use the `.center-block` class. Here is an example of that:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default center-block">Center me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex and solve this.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

or other way with CSS justify-content.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp